# Cannot download Saved AI Models in Kaggle working dir, and models were lost

Tags: machine-learning, kaggle, saving-data, data-persistence

I ran a CNN model for image analysis, my model and weights saved to kaggle/working, however I spent hours trying to download these using combination of methods, clicking the … adjacnent to the file and selecting 'Download' did not work, no response .

So i shut web browser and laptop down and rebooted and looked back in Notebook editor and the files were no longer there in kaggle/working so i need to run my model again - what I am missing- should these files persist and is there an issue with the 'Download' button?
If i am not saving in correct place , where should I save so files persist ? The 'Output' in my notebook interface only holds a log of events recorded at runtime.

I have modified my code to create links and save to local machine just in case I have further issues:

```
import shutil
import os
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Specify the save directory on your local machine
save_directory = '/Users/callanmooneys/Downloads/'

# Define the save path in Kaggle
save_path = '/kaggle/working/'

# Define the model name, subject, and accuracy
model_name = model.input_names[0][:-6]
subject = "ALL_Classification"
acc = test_score[1] * 100

# Save model
save_id = f'{model_name}-{subject}-{acc:.2f}.h5'
model_save_loc = os.path.join(save_path, save_id)
model.save(model_save_loc)
print(f"Model was saved as {model_save_loc}")

# Save model copy to local machine
local_model_save_loc = os.path.join(save_directory, save_id)
shutil.copy(model_save_loc, local_model_save_loc)
print(f"Model was also saved as {local_model_save_loc}")

# Generate download link for model
model_download_link = f'<a href="file://{local_model_save_loc}" download="{save_id}">Download Model</a>'
display(HTML(model_download_link))

# Save weights
weight_save_id = f'{model_name}-{subject}-weights.h5'
weights_save_loc = os.path.join(save_path, weight_save_id)
model.save_weights(weights_save_loc)
print(f"Weights were saved as {weights_save_loc}")

# Save weights copy to local machine
local_weights_save_loc = os.path.join(save_directory, weight_save_id)
shutil.copy(weights_save_loc, local_weights_save_loc)
print(f"Weights were also saved as {local_weights_save_loc}")

# Generate download link for weights
weights_download_link = f'<a href="file://{local_weights_save_loc}" download="{weight_save_id}">Download Weights</a>'
display(HTML(weights_download_link))
```

Thanks In Advance`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

This feedback may be useful to new Kaggle notebook users like myself;

1. To allow internet access in Kaggle notebook (it is disabled by default ) , you must enable via the very small / easy to miss 'arrow ' button bottom left hand side of notebook, this reveals  a sliding menu with option to enable Internet access.
2. Saving and downloading models and model weights:
   The models will not appear in your 'Output' in Notebook interface / overview.
   You need to  save to

> '/kaggle/working/'

directory, which is accessible again via sliding menu (see above)
These files ***will not persist by default***, you must allow 'File' Persistence via sliding menu (see above), otherwise you may well lose your data like I did.

[image]